# How to get the database name from wp-config.php using wp-cli call?

Tags: wordpress

I am writing a perl script for migrating Wordpress installations from a place to another. In this work I need to get wordpress database name from wp-config file using wp-cli calls. So please let me know how call wp-cli function from perl script for getting db name from wp-config.php.

Comment: i used perl file handling to read db name from wp-config.php. But same is not possible with wp-cli calls? I am also want to add some new line s to wp-config.php

Comment: I don't know how use wp cli for add some new line s to wp-config.php. Only thing i know is wp core update command to update core

Answer (score 12):

Assuming you already figured out how to call an external process from Perl, this is the wp-cli command you'll need:

```
wp eval 'echo DB_NAME;'
```

Answer (score 3):

Another way to get it, without using eval, is to run

```
wp config get DB_NAME
```